# How to add quotes beetwen words in a list in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I have the following list:

```
[torunn,sentry,moonstone,avispa,phil coulson]
```

Is it possible to change it to this using Vim?:

```
["torunn","sentry","moonstone","avispa","phil coulson"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Substitute Ex Command is a Nice Tool to Manipulate CSV Lines**

I often times manipulate CSVs using the substitute Ex command.

In this case I just match the values in your set through a character range:

`[ a-zA-Z]`

-> similar to `\w`, but your set does not have `_0-9` and we need spaces.

I place this in a character group using the escaped parenthesis.

Also, since we can have a comma or a end bracket next, I create another character group and allow for either character using the alternation operator:

`\(,\|\]\)`

Checking our pattern match here:
[image]

These character groups are then referenced in the replacement string (and include the quotations).

Pulling it all together, here is the substitution command:

```
:s/\([ a-zA-Z]\+\)\(,\|\]\)/"\1"\2/g
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

---

**Less Over Engineered Solution**

As @bimlas has indicated, a less over engineered solution would be as follows:

`:s/[^,]\+/"\0"/g`

The `\0` just is reference to the whole matched pattern (see `:help \0`).

Comment: A shorter equivalent: `s/[^,]\+/"\0"/g` (cannot try, I'm on Android)

Comment: Agreed, The non-comma character approach makes more sense and it is simpler.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a substitution:

```
s/\v(\w|\s)+/"&"/g
```

This will match one ore more (`+`) occurrences of the word `\w` or space `\s` character. The replacement string `"&"` is the matched pattern `&` surrounded by quotes. The `&` character is described in `:help s/\&`

Answer (score 2):

With the help of [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) and a macro, it's easy:

I assume your cursor is on the first letter ("t", in this case): `qqys/\v,|]<cr>"nlq99@q`

Let's break it down step by step:

```
qqys/\v,|]<cr>"nlq99@q
qq               q       # record a macro in the q register
  ys                     # surround something with something
    /\v,|]<cr>           # search for comma or closing bracket
              "          # surround until there with double-quotes
               n         # jump to the next match
                l        # go one to the right
                  99@q   # run the macro 99 times (will stop at first failure)
```

The search query `\v,|]` is just turning on `v`ery magic mode, and then matching comma or (`|`) closing bracket. We don't need to escape the bracket, because we didn't open one.

Comment: Without surround: `wqqciw"<c-r>""<esc>wq5@q`

Comment: @PeterRincker That doesn't correctly account for multi-word elements, but `wqqc/\v,|]<cr>"<c-r>""<esc>wq5@q` should work